# how to call phtml file in controller?

Tags: magento

I need to show minicart in topbar when user will click on add to cart. i have created a file named `topcart.phtml` at this location

`app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/template/checkout/cart/mycart.phtml.`

Now i am calling this block in my controller file and returning the response to show mini cart.

```
$sidebar_block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('mycart');
$sidebar = $sidebar_block->toHtml();
$response['sidebar'] = $sidebar;
```

but it is showing this error

> "Fatal error: Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object " in
>   my controller file.

Do i need to call mycart.phtml file in layout also or any other location?

mycart.phtml

```
<?php $_cartQty = $this->getSummaryCount() ?>



<div class="shoppingcart">



    <div class="fadelink">

        <div class="shopping_cart_mini hidden-phone hidden-tablet <?php if(!$_cartQty) echo 'empty'; ?>">



<div class="close1">X</div>

            <div class="inner-wrapper">

              <?php $_items = $this->getRecentItems() ?>
<?php  print_r($_items);  ?>
              <?php if(count($_items)): ?>

                <?php echo $this->__('Recently added item(s)') ?>



                <?php foreach($_items as $_item): ?>

                    <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>

                <?php endforeach; ?>



                <div class="wrapper"> <a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCartUrl(); ?>" class="button"><?php echo $this->__('View shopping cart') ?></a> <a href="<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl() ?>" class="button"><?php echo $this->__('Proceed to Checkout') ?></a> </div>

              <?php else: ?>

                <span class="empty"><?php echo $this->__('You have no items in your shopping cart.') ?></span>

              <?php endif ?>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<script>

    jQuery(".close1").click(function() 

    {

        jQuery(".shoppingcart").css("display", "none"); 

        jQuery(".shopping_cart_mini").css("display", "none");

    });



</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to `loadLyaout` first

```
$this->loadLayout();
$sidebar_block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('mycart');
$sidebar = $sidebar_block->toHtml();
$response['sidebar'] = $sidebar;
```

direct method

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('checkout/cart/mycart.phtml')->toHtml();
```

as you can see these are use in xml

```
<block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml" before="-">
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_sidebar.extra_actions" as="extra_actions" translate="label" module="checkout">
                    <label>Shopping Cart Sidebar Extra Actions</label>
                </block>
            </block>
```

Comment: Yes i am using $this->loadLayout();

Comment: you have to paste your full code. adn your xml too .did you define this block `mycart` in xml?

Comment: i added the direct method add your block name in place of `core/template`.

Comment: with direct method do i need to define this in xml file also?

Comment: In this way it shows minicart html. but showing empty cart message.In my cart i have added many items.i have pasted code of mycart.phtml file also.

Comment: you have to use direct other wise you have the xml too because it is using the child html